# Using TypoScriptFrontendController features in AuthenticationService? / Save Data to User in Authenticator?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, typo3, deprecated, typo3-10.x

So I use a Service Class (extends from `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationService`) to authenticate our Frontend Users using OAuth2. These Services are automatically instantiated and called via Typos own Middleware: FrontendUserAuthenticator.
In this class I used to save data from the authentication result to `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user` using `setKey('ses', 'key', 'data')`, which seems is not possible anymore since v10. How would I go about still doing this?

The documentation is sparse
https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.4/Deprecation-85878-EidUtilityAndVariousTSFEMethods.html
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Context/Index.html

I've tried the following:

- constructor injecting the TSFE using DI

```php
class FrontendOAuthService extends AuthenticationService
{
    public function __construct(TypoScriptFrontendController $TSFE) {
```

=> `LogicException: TypoScriptFrontendController was tried to be injected before initial creation`

- changing the Middlewares order to have it instantiate before the Auth Middleware

```php
(packages/extension_name/Configuration/RequestMiddlewares.php)

return [
    'frontend' => [
        'typo3/cms-frontend/tsfe' => [
            'disabled' => true,
        ],
        'vendor/extension_name/frontend-oauth' => [
            'target' => \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Middleware\TypoScriptFrontendInitialization::class,
            'before' => [
                'typo3/cms-frontend/authentication',
            ],
            'after' => [
                'typo3/cms-frontend/eid',
                'typo3/cms-frontend/page-argument-validator',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

=> `UnexpectedValueException: Your dependencies have cycles. That will not work out.`

- instantiating the TSFE myself

```php
/** @var ObjectManager $objectManager */
$objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
/** @var DealerService $dealerService */
$lang = $site->getDefaultLanguage();
$siteLanguage = $objectManager->get(SiteLanguage::class, $lang->getLanguageId(), $lang->getLocale(), $lang->getBase(), []);
/** @var TypoScriptFrontendController $TSFE */
$TSFE = $objectManager->get(
    TypoScriptFrontendController::class,
    GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Context::class),
    $site,
    $siteLanguage,
    GeneralUtility::_GP('no_cache'),
    GeneralUtility::_GP('cHash')
);
```

=> the $TSFE->fe_user is an emptystring ("")

- using the `UserAspect`

```php
/** @var Context $context */
$context = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Context::class);
$feUser = $context->getAspect('frontend.user');
$feUser->set...
```

=> Aspects are read-only

- adding vars to the user data in the `getUser` method of the AuthenticationService

```php
(packages/extension_name/Classes/Service/FrontendOAuthService.php)

public function getUser()
{
    $user = allBusinessCodeHere();
    $user['my_own_key'] = 'myData';
    return $user;
```

=> is not propagated to the `UserAspect(frontend.user)` nor the `$TSFE->fe_user`

I'm out of ideas guys.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when i wanted to use redirects with record links.
I ended up disabling the original redirect middleware and adding my own with a mocked version of tsfe.
The extension can be found here:
https://github.com/BenjaminBeck/bdm_middleware_redirect_with_tsfe

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I had the same issue and was able to solve it:

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/10.0/Breaking-88540-ChangedRequestWorkflowForFrontendRequests.html states:

> Storing session data from a Frontend User Session / Anonymous session
> is now triggered within the Frontend User
> (frontend-user-authenticator) Middleware, at a later point - once the
> page was generated. Up until TYPO3 v9, this was part of the
> RequestHandler logic right after content was put together. This was
> due to legacy reasons of the previous hook execution order. Migration
> Consider using a PSR-15 middleware instead of using a hook, or
> explicitly call storeSessionData() within the PHP hook if necessary.

In my `MyAuthenticationService extends AbstractAuthenticationService` in method `getUser()` I set `$_SESSION['myvendor/myextension/accessToken']` to the token received by the external oauth service. In my `SaveSessionMiddleware` I save this token to the `FrontendUserAuthentication` object using `setKey()` which by then is available:

EXT:myextension/Configuration/RequestMiddlewares.php

```
return [
    'frontend' => [
        'myvendor/myextension/save-session-middleware' => [
            'target' => \MyVendor\MyExtension\Middleware\SaveSessionMiddleware::class,
            'after' => [
                'typo3/cms-frontend/authentication',
            ],
        ]
    ]
];
```

EXT:myextension/Classes/Middleware/SaveSessionMiddleware.php

```
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\MiddlewareInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Authentication\FrontendUserAuthentication;

class SaveSessionMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface {

    /**
     * @param ServerRequestInterface $request
     * @param RequestHandlerInterface $handler
     * @return ResponseInterface
     */
    public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): ResponseInterface {
        if (!empty($_SESSION['myvendor/myextension/accessToken'])) {
            $this->getFrontendUserAuthentication()->setKey(
                'ses',
                'myvendor/myextension/accessToken',
                $_SESSION['myvendor/myextension/accessToken']);
            unset($_SESSION['myvendor/myextension/accessToken']);
        }

        return $handler->handle($request);
    }

    private function getFrontendUserAuthentication(): FrontendUserAuthentication {
        return $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user;
    }
}
```